# adding html5 attribute to my website

Tags: html, web

As some of you may have seen arcade fire released a special music video along with google that showcased the power of HTML5, if not its here: http://thewildernessdowntown.com/ 
My question is I'm redesigning my home page and would really like to add those birds but when i went through the websites source code i couldnt find the script anywhere and when i just took the entire html source file, saved it locally and opened it, the page opened perfectly, but no birds. Can anyone show or help me pinpoint the birds on the website so i can use them. THANKS

Comment: I'm not sure you can just take the code for your own website. When you do find the source code, make sure you check the license on it.

Comment: its only for a my own crappy website. im jsut trying to learn how it works more then anything else

Comment: The code for the birds is going to be buried in the javascript which is compressed and minified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing the source, I came across this linked javascript file - http://www.thewildernessdowntown.com/js/main-compressed.js

There is A LOT of stuff going on in there, but I found a function that might be somewhat helpful (though it seems a bit obfuscated.)

```
addBirds1: function() {
    for (var e = 0; e < 100; e++) {
        var c = -1 - Math.random() * 0.5;
        var h = 1 - Math.random() * 2;
        var b = 1 + Math.random() * 0.5;
        var f = 1 - Math.random() * 2 - Math.random() * 0.5;
        var k = 1.5 * (0.025 + Math.random() * 0.05);
        var m = (b - c) / k;
        var l = (f - h) / k;
        var g = Math.atan2(l, m);
        this.birds_array.push({
            start: {
                x: c,
                y: h
            },
            end: {
                x: b,
                y: f
            },
            d: {
                x: m,
                y: l
            },
            a: g,
            t: k,
            o: Math.random(),
            scale: 0.4 + 0.4 * Math.random()
        })
    }
},
```

There are 3 versions of that function... so I'd imagine they are just ways to simulate random flying activity. It seems that what you're looking for is javascript, and not HTML5

Answer (score 0):

The birds feature is not HTML5. It's [javascript](http://cdn.thewildernessdowntown.com/js/main-compressed.js). Turn off your javascript and check it out.

http://cdn.thewildernessdowntown.com/js/main-compressed.js

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 doesn't do that, sorry. It's still a markup language. You'll still have to use good ol' Javascript for that. You can see that on the website if you turn Javascript off.